# How to fix warning about "dependency is ignored for debug..."

Tags: java, android, json, gradle

I have java module, that used not only for android projects, but also for java projects. Java module used `json`, so it has dependency:

```
compile 'org.json:json:20160810'
```

Of couse, on build android project I has warning:

> WARNING: Dependency org.json:json:20160810 is ignored for debug as it
>   may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
>            In case of problem, please repackage with jarjar to change the class packages

I'm use module with sources, not as jar and I do not want install module to local repository.

How I can fix issue with warning?

I know, that for jar I can use `exclude group/module`, but it do not work for module.

Comment: Have you fixed it? Otherwise post your gradle build file

Comment: @penguin, sorry I now switched to another job (not android) and can not answser to you. But I get answser as quick, as can in future.